# What is the yield for?

Tags: ruby

What is the purpose of yield in Ruby? Could someone explain it ?  I don't understand what yield does:

```
def variable(&block)
    puts 'Here goes:'
    case block.arity
        when 0
            yield
        when 1
            yield 'one'
        when 2
            yield 'one', 'two'
        when 3
            yield 'one', 'two', 'three'
    end
    puts 'Done!'
end
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use yield to implicitly call the block. You are defining where to call the block if there's a block given. For example:

```
def test
   puts "You are in the method"
   yield
   puts "You are again back to the method"
   yield
end
test {puts "You are in the block"}
```

That will results in

```
You are in the method
You are in the block
You are again back to the method
You are in the block
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If a method is invoked with a block then the method can `yield` control to the block (call the block) with some arguments, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Any method can be called with a block as an implicit argument. Inside the method, you can call the block using the yield keyword with a value.
A method can then invoke an associated block one or more time using the Ruby yield statement. Thus any method that wants to take a block as a parameter can use the yield keyword to execute the block at any time:

```
=begin  
  Ruby Code blocks are chunks of code between braces or  
  between do..end that you can associate with method invocations  
=end  
def call_block  
  puts 'Start of method'  
  # you can call the block using the yield keyword  
  yield  
  yield  
  puts 'End of method'  
end  
# Code blocks may appear only in the source adjacent to a method call  
call_block {puts 'In the block'}
```

The output is:

```
 >ruby p022codeblock.rb  
    Start of method  
    In the block  
    In the block  
    End of method  
    >Exit code: 0
```

If you provide a code block when you call a method, then inside the method, you can `yield` control to that code block - suspend execution of the method; execute the code in the block; and return control to the method body, right after the call to yield. If no code block is passed and `yield` is called, Ruby raises an exception.